# Error with .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete

Tags: excel, vba

Have read numerous posts on this with various suggestions, can't seem to get past this error.

I have a series of code blocks which look for various data in column I of my spreadsheet. If that data is found, then the row should be deleted. I want to do delete all but the header row, and so my blocks of code are as follows (1 example):

```
Sub Strip()
With Columns("I")
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=70-79%", VisibleDropDown:=False
    .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter
End With
End Sub
```

When I step through this, and get to the Offset line, it does select the proper criteria, however when stepping past that line, I get the error: Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or Object-defined error.

Any ideas?

Comment: `Columns("I")` Change that to a range like `Range("I1:I" & lastrow)`

Answer (score 3):

Like I mentioned in the comment, You need to change your column to a range.

Try this (**Untested**)

```
Sub Strip()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = Sheet1

    With ws
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        lRow = .Range("I" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set Rng = .Range("I1:I" & lRow)

        With Rng
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=70-79%", VisibleDropDown:=False
            .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With

        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, +1 for beating me in the comment ;)

Comment: So I tried the longer block, still threw the error 1004 at the offset line, then tried substituting to use the UsedRange option, so:

Comment: With UsedRange.Columns("I")
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=70-79%", VisibleDropDown:=False
    .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter
End With

Comment: Wow not sure why you can't use carriage return in your comments without it posting the comment rather than moving down a line, but in any event the block I posted above throws a 424 object required error.

Comment: @JoeWilson: I made a small change. Now use my code and test

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> With Columns("I")
> ...
> .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
> ```

You cannot `offset` down an entire column. Try the `UsedRange.Columns("I")`, or something that is sure to include your data but not an entire column. The `UsedRange` needs explicit qualification to some worksheet, so if your code is not in a worksheet code module, qualify it either to some explicit sheet or to `ActiveSheet`.

```
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("I")
```

Comment: @SiddharthRout you were writing a comment, I was writing an answer :P